# Extract value from Future using Cats

Tags: scala, future, scala-cats, github4s

I am trying to write a small library for GitHub's API. And I am trying to simulate the behavior of [Github4s's library](https://47deg.github.io/github4s/docs.html), here is an example of this library:

```
val user1 = Github(accessToken).users.get("rafaparadela")
object ProgramEval {
    val u1 = user1.exec[Eval, HttpResponse[String]]().value
 }

import cats.implicits._
import github4s.GithubResponses.GHResult

ProgramEval.u1 match {
  // Here the actual value of the request is returned, 
  // not the same as Future's onComplete, where the return type is Unit
  case Right(GHResult(result, status, headers)) => result.login
  case Left(e) => e.getMessage
}
```

I am quoting the docs:

> Every Github4s API call returns a GHIO[GHResponse[A]] which is an alias for Free[Github4s, GHResponse[A]].
>
> GHResponse[A] is, in turn, a type alias for Either[GHException, GHResult[A]].
>
> GHResult contains the result A given by Github as well as the status code and headers of the response:

At some point, they are making an `HttpRequest` using [HttpClient.scala](https://github.com/47deg/github4s/blob/master/github4s/shared/src/main/scala/github4s/HttpClient.scala)

How could I replicate this behavior myself? I have tried using Cats.Eval as in the example, but I end up having the same `Future[String]`.

Also, I an facing with some nesting problems as I make request, for example, to get a list of contributors of an organization I need to make two `HttpRequest`:

- One for getting the organization repos
- One for each repo in order to get a list of contributors

This result on a `Future[List[Future[Users]]]`, and I face the same problem as above, in order to obtain the results, I have to do:

```
(result:Future[List[Future[Users]]]) onComplete { users =>
    users.foreach {
        _  onComplete {
            // Process result
        }
    }
}
```

But I would like to return the value, as `github4s`. I've been reading about [Cats's Applicative and Traversable Functors](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/applicativetraverse.html) without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `List[Future]` to `Future[List]` using `Future.sequence` and then squash nested futures.

The resulting code:

```
val input: Future[List[Future[Users]]] = ???
implicit  val ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.global
val result: Future[List[Users]] = input.flatMap(list => Future.sequence(list))
```

Comment: Thanks!, will try when I get home. And as for returning the Future value instead of just consume it?

Comment: Not sure that I totally get your point regarding returning vs consuming. This code gives you `Future[List[Users]]`. Preferred way to consume it is to call `map/flatMap` transformations on it. `onComplete` is usually not the best solution.

Comment: But if I `map/flatMap` on a `Future` the only way I can process the result is on `onComplete`, How can then `github4s` get the result of the API request into a variable?

Comment: Both `Future` and `GHIO` represent a computation that can fail or never terminate. So extracting `A` from  `Future[A]` is an unsafe operation which should be done at the latest possible stage. 

This is the code sample from the docs you provided:

Comment: `val u3 = Github(accessToken).users.get("dialelo").execFuture[HttpResponse[String]]()
  Await.result(u3, 2.seconds)`

Comment: So at the end, they are executing an `Await.result`, when using Futures, but how could they do it with The above example? using `Cats.Eval`?

Comment: can't tell you much about `Eval` but it has `.value` function to extract the result

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you think this problem will be solved by cats. It seems what you want in the end is the `String` (body value), not `Future[String]`.

The only way you can extract a value from a Future is to block your main thread waiting on it using `Await`. As that is not very efficient you can create a callback using `onComplete` as you did.

The important thing to notice is that once you wrap something in `Future`, most of the time you don't want to get it back. When you do it is usually on edge of the program (for example your main thread).

Let's take your problem: `val f = Future[List[Future[Users]]]`. To get this unnested you need to:

`f.flatMap(Future.sequence)` gives you `Future[List[Users]]`.

`Future.sequence` will make `Future[List[Future[Users]]]` into `Future[Future[List[Users]]]`. It merges all the Futures in the list into a single one. Any failed future will make the outer future be a failure. If you don't want that, you can `.recover` each inner Future.

`f.flatMap`will make `Future[Future[List[Users]]` into `Future[List[Users]]`. It runs the inner Future after the outer one finishes. Same for error handling as above here.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I got confused with how the library uses `Cats.Eval`, and somewhat I thought they were using cats to extract the body of the request.